# IBM installation manager cannot be launched in fedora 17(64bit)

Tags: 64-bit, websphere

Here's the error msg goes when i try to run the IBM installation manager:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    /opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/447/1/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-3659.so (libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
    swt-pi-gtk (Not found in java.library.path)
    /tmp/swtlib-32/libswt-pi-gtk-3659.so (libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
    /tmp/swtlib-32/libswt-pi-gtk.so (/tmp/swtlib-32/lib/libswt-pi-gtk.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

However, those files does exist. I also already have SWT lib installed. Any one have experience on this issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IBM Installation Manager can only run if 32bit GTK components installed.
Here are the packages I install on Redhat 64bit in order to run IBM Installation Manager:

[Install required packages for IBM Installation Manager UI on Redhat x64](https://gist.github.com/3075940)

Should be similar packages in Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember about Installation Manager but for WAS installation launching setup.jar itself did help:

```
java -jar setup.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when tried to install CM on Linux Fedora 17 x86_64 bits and this command solved my issue

```
yum install gtk2.i686 gtk2-engines.i686 PackageKit-gtk-module.i686 PackageKit-gtk-module.x86_64 libcanberra-gtk2.x86_64 libcanberra-gtk2.i686
```

After execute it i can run interactive installation.

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful for steering me in the right direction for solving the problem on rhel 6.5 on IBM power.  i installed the equivalent packages using the .ppc instead of .ppc64 files (since the installer is PPC) and then i had to add these 2 lines at the bottom of the install.ini according to ibm support article swg21688528 as follows:

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.useCairo=false

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false

- Parke